# Passing parameter ot RDL report for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I am trying to call rdl reports remotely in ASP.NET, And i was successful calling report without parameter. But when i pass parameter, reporting i not populating and not giving error. It display noting in report. find my code below. and please do suggest me on the same.

```
MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
  MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://gblon9sqm10   /ReportServer_DB10");
        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Reports/Report1";
        MyReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
        MyReportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;

        ReportParameter[] rptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
        rptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter();
        rptParameters[0].Name = "exposureType";
        rptParameters[0].Values.Add("Impressions");
        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParameters);
        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Can you open the rdl file of the report and see the parameter there?

Comment: Yes i have parameter, I have created 2 report one with parameter and other without parameter. one without parameter work fine. If i pass the parameter to report without parameter i am getting error as parameter doesn't exist. When i pass the parameter to report with parameter i am not getting any error and not displaying any thing.

Comment: Are you sure the 2nd report is working correctly? What happens if you just add a label parameter to report 1 and set a parameter to that?

Comment: Yes, second one without parameter working. And if  MyReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = true; then first one is laso working but i need to select parameter in report viewer. i can't set the parameter value from .cs file

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I set this up but I remember having to make sure that you didn't setup the report again on postback. This is my code in page_load:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = Settings.ReportServerUrl;
    if (rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials == null)
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials();
    List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
    parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("TitleLabel", "Title string here"));
    //More parameters added here...
    rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with same code and configuration as you have mentioned.

I tried bit extra work and get the rid of problem.

I have created a new report with single parameter "Name" and pass value to this parameter from code-behind as ReportParameter. At the report configuration side set the type of parameter text and allow to blank values. Note here i didn't touch any other settings of parameter means kept it as comes by default.

This works for me and then i started adding more parameters and it works perfectly fine.

There is no any browser constraint.

Try as said above and still you face issue then reply me i will put a sample code.

Hope it will help you.